# Draw a few circles with numbers in a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make this figure. I can make the rectangle but I have problems drawing the circles and also putting the numbers inside the circles.[image]

Comment: We are open to have a look at your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use circular nodes for your numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,minimum size=0.8cm,circle}]
\node at (1,3) {1};
\node at (3,0) {10};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```